# Forcing a pgfkey to be executed before all the others

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

I'm executing a list of pgfkeys
`\pgfkeys{key1=val1, key2=val2, ...}`. `key2` stores `val2` to some variable `\myval`, which is used when `key1` is executed. This won't work because the keys are in the wrong order. However, the list of keys is put together by another command, and I cannot simply change their ordering.

Is it possible to define `key2` in such a way that it gets executed before all the other keys in the list? Or, alternatively, is it possible to define `key1` in such a way that it "looks ahead" for the value stored by `key2`?

Comment: The easiest is to store val1 in some other macro and do the processing after all the keys have been set, instead of using the value immediately. It would be easier show if you can provide a full and compilable example with the intended behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I had previously used ```\begin{scope}[...]\end{scope}``` instead of ```\pgfkeys{...}``` which had the problem of the macro being gone after the scope (thought there was the same problem with ```\pgfkeys``` but apparently not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your keys in a `exe` style with specified order, and execute `exe` at last.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  first/.style={},
  second/.style={},
  exe/.style={first, second},
  a/.style={first/.append style={test=#1}},
  b/.style={second/.append style={test=#1}},
  test/.store in=\test, test=0,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0, 0) {\test};
  \node[a=1, b=2, exe] at (1, 0) {\test};
  \node[b=2, a=1, exe] at (2, 0) {\test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! In my special case though I need exe to be executed before other keys that come between a and b, so that won't work (also the sole purpose of the reordering was to get rid of a key like "exe", which would have been repeated very often).